# Make JSF InputTextarea expand why adding text

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF inputTextarea

```
<div class="row">
    <h:inputTextarea id="msg_text" rows="5" class="col-xs-12"
        required="true" maxlength="4294967295"
        requiredMessage="#{msg['label.hist.request.content.message.obligatoire']}"
        value="#{requestBean.msgTextValue}"
        style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 140px;min-height:140px; border:2px solid rgb(127,127,127); margin-bottom: 5px;">
        </h:inputTextarea>          
</div>
```

I want to avoid adding scroll when i adding extrat lignes (more than 5 lignes)

[image]

Comment: Try https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml

Comment: @JasperdeVries thank's for your comment but the perfect solution will only use JSF

Comment: Then it turns out to be not a JSF but html/javascript related question. You'd change your tags.